# Comment Saver - Unposted comments are saved between page loads

Tags: script, comments

Simply stores unposted comments (using HTML5 localStorage) between page loads, so that if you leave the page you don't lose your comment.

Currently a bit hacky, but it works.

User Script:

https://gist.github.com/fredley/9ffa2debdca18ba65c50

Comment: No longer works :( since http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235255/proposed-tweak-to-comment-ui-for-long-threads was implemented, I suspect.

Comment: @Gilles I've updated the gist, working again now.

Comment: Works again, thank you! Additional suggestion: add https to the include list (HTTPS mostly works for non-meta sites these days).

Comment: The comment draft still remains behind forever, even after posting it and after blanking the input box. Have you been able to look into this?

Comment: Seemed to work for me, after I edited all the `http://` links to change them to `https://`. Without that, I think the userscript just does not get to run :-). (I'm using TamperMonkey on Firefox, in case it matters).